# How to get records on base of Date condition?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, gridview

[image]

I have a table `PersonalInformation` in SQL Server 2008. In this table there is a column `CreateDate` which stores the date for inserted record. Now I want to search record from table according to date. My search string is like `Month-Year` and `CreateDate` is stored using `GETDATE()` function of SQL Server.

If I search using the format `Month-Year`, e.g. `March-2012` I want the month and year which match with table record is displayed and also record inserted before `March-2012` also displayed.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your description is hard to understand, would you mind showing the code to which it refers?

Comment: I post my table structure so that you better understand #Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms174420.aspx) function

```
select  DATEPART(MM,'March 2012') --> 3
select  DATEPART(YYYY,'March 2012')--> 2012
```

so in your query search for

```
select * from table where DATEPART("MM" CreatedDate) = DATEPART(MM,'March 2012') AND DATEPART("YYY" CreatedDate) = DATEPART(YYY,'March 2012')
```

in this way you can check = or >= as you want.

Note that my input is `March 2012` and not `March-2012`.
For replace string use [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms186862.aspx) function int his way

```
REPLACE('March-2012','-',' ')
```

to search before your input date

```
select * from table where (DATEPART("MM" CreatedDate) <= DATEPART(MM,'March 2012') AND DATEPART("YYY" CreatedDate) = DATEPART(YYY,'March 2012') OR (DATEPART("YYY" CreatedDate) < DATEPART(YYY,'March 2012')))
```

to search after your input date

```
select * from table where (DATEPART("MM" CreatedDate) > DATEPART(MM,'March 2012') AND DATEPART("YYY" CreatedDate) = DATEPART(YYY,'March 2012') OR (DATEPART("YYY" CreatedDate) > DATEPART(YYY,'March 2012')))
```

Comment: Thanks Sir this solve half of my problem.. but if i used <= or >= it will show only those record which are in month of march. i want all the records before march should be published. @faby

Answer (score 0):

Select * from Tbl_Name where Convert(varchar,createDate,110) like '12-10'

Answer (score 0):

Try like This:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE 
CONVERT(varchar(10), DATENAME(MONTH, CreatedDate)) = 'March' // Passed From Parameter
AND Year(CreatedDate) = 2014                                 // Passed From Parameter
```

Comment: and how to get those result too which are stored before march 2014 @Pawan

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mess around with the string representation of the data and use that string for comparison.

I would suggest parsing your input date into a proper `DateTime` object first:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("March-2012", "MMMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then use this DateTime object as a `SqlParameter` with `SqlDbType.DateTime`, in your `SqlCommand` for filtering based on your `CreatedDate` column.